# What does the compiler do if a member function appears both inline and non-inline

Tags: c++, inline

I was given code to work with that appears in this form.

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
public:
  int baz() const;
};

inline int Foo::baz() const { // return whatever }
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int Foo::baz() const { // same as above }
```

Which `Foo::baz` does the compiler choose to use? Is it even necessary to provide the non-inline version since the compiler can choose to either inline the function or not inline it?

Comment: Does `foo.cpp` include `foo.h`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I'll edit it in.

Comment: AFAIK the code should not compile then as there would be multiple definitions in `foo.cpp`.  Do you know if the code actually compiles?

Comment: @NathanOliver actually it doesn't compile under GCC. I'll just remove the non-inline version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks ODR. For inline functions there is possible only one definition per compilation unit. Program may contain multiple definitions, as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit. Code you demonstrate is ill-formed, although some compilers may accept it under relaxed rules.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` makes it's ok for the compiler to see the function (or variable) more than once. But it must be the same every time or it's undefined behavior.